# MacOS Python - Jupiter notebook not showing anything

Tags: python, macos, installation

I installed python3.12 with packages&libreries, pip, home-brew Jupyter etc. on Mac.

One with just running commands I can find online and created a project files in Documents - Jupyter notebook worked fine, showed me the folders and files, but, then I was having issue getting Maths and or frameworks. and learned about having everything in a virtual environment might be better.

I tried second install in a 'Venv' but on Desktop this time - so the pythonpro/bin is located in this new folder on desktop. now when I run Jupyter notebook, it starts blank - it does not show anything - not even where you can access terminal etc. I have attached both the install information screen.

I start everything by, ~ cd desktop then, ~ source pythonpro/bin/activate then, ~ jupyter notebook

question would be either, how to move everything from the first install to desktop folder or correct what what went wrong in the second location (desktop).

Thanks for your help!

```
Last login: Tue Mar  5 12:39:35 on ttys000
➜  ~ which -a python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3
➜  ~ ls -l /usr/bin/python*
-rwxr-xr-x  76 root  wheel  168160 Feb  2 18:19 /usr/bin/python3
➜  ~ ls -l /usr/local/bin/python*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  70 Feb 23 12:14 /usr/local/bin/python3 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  77 Feb 23 12:14 /usr/local/bin/python3-config -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  78 Feb 23 12:14 /usr/local/bin/python3-intel64 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3-intel64
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  73 Feb 23 12:14 /usr/local/bin/python3.12 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3.12
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  80 Feb 23 12:14 /usr/local/bin/python3.12-config -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3.12-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  81 Feb 23 12:14 /usr/local/bin/python3.12-intel64 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3.12-intel64
➜  ~ ls -l /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python*
lrwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin      10 Feb 23 12:14 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3 -> python3.12
lrwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin      17 Feb 23 12:14 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3-config -> python3.12-config
lrwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin      18 Feb 23 12:14 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3-intel64 -> python3.12-intel64
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin  152624 Feb  6 23:15 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3.12
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin    2084 Feb  6 23:10 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3.12-config
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin   70544 Feb  6 23:14 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3.12-intel64
➜  ~ which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3
➜  ~ which pip3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/pip3
➜  ~
```

Edited:
super questions!
-- Python was installed using python.org package version 3.12 - I also installed Homebrew and a lot of other stuff - which don't recall though - any way I can check that?

--- I have iTerm installed and ~ just showed up :(. I get this line even in terminal.

---

`➜ ~ which jupyter /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/jupyter ➜ ~`
python -m jupyter notebook - yup, it doesn't work either.

---- Yes I have installed some packages e.g. Math, Pandas, Numpy etc.. including Jupyter lab and notebook –

---

### Edit 2!

---

```
➜  ~ cd desktop
➜  desktop source pythonpro/bin/activate
(PythonPro) ➜  desktop jupyter notebook
[I 2024-03-07 11:06:35.259 ServerApp] jupyter_lsp | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-03-07 11:06:35.261 ServerApp] jupyter_server_terminals | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-03-07 11:06:35.262 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-03-07 11:06:35.264 ServerApp] notebook | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-03-07 11:06:35.480 ServerApp] notebook_shim | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-03-07 11:06:35.505 ServerApp] notebook_shim | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-03-07 11:06:35.506 ServerApp] jupyter_lsp | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-03-07 11:06:35.506 ServerApp] jupyter_server_terminals | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-03-07 11:06:35.507 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /Users/mbpro/Desktop/pythonpro/lib/python3.12/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 2024-03-07 11:06:35.507 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /Users/mbpro/Desktop/pythonpro/share/jupyter/lab
[I 2024-03-07 11:06:35.508 LabApp] Extension Manager is 'pypi'.
[I 2024-03-07 11:06:35.525 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-03-07 11:06:35.527 ServerApp] notebook | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-03-07 11:06:35.527 ServerApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /Users/mbpro/Desktop
[I 2024-03-07 11:06:35.527 ServerApp] Jupyter Server 2.12.5 is running at:
[I 2024-03-07 11:06:35.527 ServerApp] http://localhost:8888/tree?token=e51e4f84ed8800dc575c8d586a4093e33eb2036501dcd625
[I 2024-03-07 11:06:35.527 ServerApp]     http://127.0.0.1:8888/tree?token=e51e4f84ed8800dc575c8d586a4093e33eb2036501dcd625
[I 2024-03-07 11:06:35.527 ServerApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 2024-03-07 11:06:35.530 ServerApp]

    To access the server, open this file in a browser:
        file:///Users/mbpro/Library/Jupyter/runtime/jpserver-2274-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/tree?token=e51e4f84ed8800dc575c8d586a4093e33eb2036501dcd625
        http://127.0.0.1:8888/tree?token=e51e4f84ed8800dc575c8d586a4093e33eb2036501dcd625
[I 2024-03-07 11:06:35.540 ServerApp] Skipped non-installed server(s): bash-language-server, dockerfile-language-server-nodejs, javascript-typescript-langserver, jedi-language-server, julia-language-server, pyright, python-language-server, python-lsp-server, r-languageserver, sql-language-server, texlab, typescript-language-server, unified-language-server, vscode-css-languageserver-bin, vscode-html-languageserver-bin, vscode-json-languageserver-bin, yaml-language-server
```

Comment: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3`: that doesn't look like a Homebrew Python. How did you install Python?

Comment: Could you format your question to also show the relevant commands as code? Because `~ cd desktop then, ~ source pythonpro/bin/activate then, ~ jupyter notebook` reads awkward, in particular the `~` (is that your prompt??)

Comment: Where is `which jupyter` though?

Comment: Have you tried starting Jupyter with `python -m jupyter notebook`?

Comment: If you created a virtual environment, you'll also need to (re)install Jupyter in that virtual environment. A newly created v-env is rather empty with packages: no Jupyter, no NumPy etc; probably only setuptools and pip are available in a new-venv.

Comment: super questions!
-- Python was installed using python.org 3.12 version - I also installed Homebrew and a lot of other stuff - which don't recall though - any way I can check that?
---
I have iTerm installed and ~ just showed up :(. I get this line even in terminal.
----
```
➜  ~ which jupyter
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/jupyter
➜  ~
```
python -m jupyter notebook - yup, it doesn't work either.
----
Yes I have installed some packages e.g. Math, Pandas, Numpy etc.. including Jupyter lab and notebook

Comment: Hm, all good so far. So when you say "doesn't work", do you mean the command immediately returns to the prompt? Or is something running, but no output from the command (it just hangs)?

Comment: HI @9769953, the command runs fine, web page opens but nothing is shown on the page, not even the menu - it is completely empty. before the virtual environment everything was working fine. I have pasted some code when I run python -m jupyter notebook or Jupyter notebook in the main question maybe that can give some clues?
Thanks!

Comment: One this if see the where python gives 3 locations - can it be that I have messed up dependancy or some of that order?
➜  ~ which -a python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3

Comment: It looks like this may be on the browser, if you get a blank webpage. The output from the jupyter command itself looks fine. Which browser do you use? See if you can open the link in another browser, if you have one.

Comment: @9769953, I mostly use safari and I thought that was the issue at first and tried Firefox but same issue.

Comment: @9769953, Issue resolved! After reading your comment, I started think if I should clear cash data for localhost - and ran everything again, and it worked :)
Thank you for ask all of the questions it helps to think about different things!